# Should I call add-to-list in Emacs Lisp a destructive function?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

add-to-list is often used to add an element to a list if the element is not in the list.

```
(let* ((aa (list 1 2 3))
       (bb aa))
  (add-to-list 'aa 0)
  (list :aa aa :bb bb))

=> (:aa (0 1 2 3) :bb (1 2 3))
```

Should one call add-to-front a destructive function because it changes the meaning of name aa? Or should it be called non-destructive because the list that aa used to point to is intact?

```
(let* ((cc (list 1 2 3))
       (dd cc))
  (add-to-list 'cc 0 t)
  (list :cc cc :dd dd))

=> (:cc (1 2 3 0) :dd (1 2 3))
```

For Emacs newbies wondering why bb and dd equals (1 2 3), feel free to open a separate stackoverflow question for that and leave a link with "add comment" button. For Emacs newbies wondering why some fellow newbies would wonder that, replace (add-to-list 'aa 0) with (setcar aa 111) and see.

For Lispers who don't use Emacs, here's a simplified definition of add-to-list

```
(defun simple-add-to-list (list-var element &optional append)
  "Add ELEMENT to the value of LIST-VAR if it isn't there yet.
If ELEMENT is added, it is added at the beginning of the list,
unless the optional argument APPEND is non-nil, in which case
ELEMENT is added at the end.
The return value is the new value of LIST-VAR."
  (let ((lst (symbol-value list-var)))
    (if (member element lst)
        lst
      (set list-var
           (if append
               (append lst (list element))
             (cons element lst))))))
```

Comment: This use of `add-to-list` on a let-bound variable is *strongly* discouraged, and does not work with `lexical-binding`.  Better use something like `cl-pushnew`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's capable of modifying the list passed to it, then it's destructive.

If a function takes a list via a symbol, it should be automatically assumed to be destructive, no?  Otherwise why not just take the list itself?

Comment: setcar take the list itself and changes its car. the reason add-to-list takes a list via a symbol is to be able to make the name refer to a new cons cell.

Comment: I did NOT claim the inverse relationship.  Your explanation of why add-to-list takes a symbol already says that it's destructive.